# IntelliJ IDEA does not see my environment variables

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I've configured an environment variable in `~/.bashrc` as well as `~/.profile`.

When I run my application via IDEA's Gradle Configuration, my environment variable is apparently not available. E.g. I am referencing this variable within `application.yml`, but the default value is being used instead. Running Gradle from the command line correctly picks up my variable.

How can I configure IDEA to load this environment variable in a global way, so I don't have to manually add it to every project where I need it (~20 projects)?

Note: running on Manjaro Linux v18.

Comment: Do you use Gradle Run/Debug Configuration? Do you have Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle** enabled? Make also sure you have **Pass parent environment variables** option enabled: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eihfr582bf89zt5/gradle_rc_env_vars.png?dl=0 (btw you can check if the evn. variable is listed in that dialog) and use the same JDK and gradle version in IDE as in terminal.

Comment: Yes, it's a Gradle build. I _do not_ have "Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle" checked, but I _do_ have "Include parent environment variables" checked. Didn't even notice the "Show" option there, and the one I care about is not in the list!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out IDEA will pick up environment variables if you define them either in e.g. `/etc/environment` or `/etc/profile` or if you use ZSH, `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: It is ok Josh. So, the only problem that is still there is that IntelliJ does not provide a project wide way to define environment variables right from the program user interface. I think it would be a great feature indeed.

Comment: it does have that feature. You can set environment variables from  Run/Debug Configurations -> Environment Variables -> clicking the icon within the box

Answer (score 1):

After setting variables, you to execute `source ~/.bashrc` and `source profile` to update and execute the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

@ josh-m I ran into the same problem in my IntelliJ IDEA setup with Maven.

In the end, I continued to keep the settings on each project, as there were not many, but when I studied the problem I found this IntelliJ support link:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141832

At least at that time, this functionality was not available in IntelliJ directly, although the following plugin, mentioned in the comments of the support article, could perhaps be of some help:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile/

Answer (score -1):

```
launchctl setenv HADOOP_VERSION 3.1.1.7.2.8.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Execute in this way to set your environment variables in MacOS for them to be used by other applications.
After that restart your IDE.